# Flash Builder / php / mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, flash-builder

I am trying to use a php function with Flash Builder... However, the return value of the function is unexpected.. a blank `[]` (object) instead of an array.
The function is :

```
public function getAllAuctions($search) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename WHERE name LIKE ?");      
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $search);        
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();


        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $rows = array();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->name);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          $rows[] = $row;
          $row = new stdClass();
          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->name);
        }

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $rows;
    }
```

[image: The data service - others work just fine]

[image: Testing function]

To sum up ... I am expecting to receive an array, result of a mysql search query; receiving a blank object instead: `[]`
Any ideas?

Comment: Curious how you are detecting an error with `$this->throwExceptionOnError();` Not sure what the point of `$rows[] = $row;` is because `$row` isn't set prior so logically, you'll always miss the last result. Thirdly, I think, when using `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` you must alter your query to select your column names, you shouldn't call `*`. (I may be wrong on that point so please correct me). Fourth, it seems there's just far too many issues with this code. I feel like reading the [reading the man page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) may be a better way to narrow the issues.

Comment: I have to confess that I am a complete beginner at php. The function comes as template when connecting to a data service; just replaced the name of the `$search` variable and slight mysql modification (`LIKE`). It was suposed to work with `select *`... I suspect that the errors get passed trough the Zend Framework which gets installed during the process...

Comment: I was thinking of buying Flash Builder but am not so sure now.. trying to work around with eclipse... too bad... I have to start all over again.. learn Java... the error seems suspicious enough ... bits translate to 5b 5d ...

Comment: I think the issue is in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $search);` ... it's supposed to be "s" from string, instead of "i" from integer... didn't try it out yet...

Comment: Yes.... that was the problem.... took me about a month to figure out.... "s" instead of "i".... I knew I had it working before somehow.... finally....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the bind parameter section: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $search);` ....
it was supposed to be: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $search);`